# XmlNodes stripping out HTML

Tags: html, xmlnode

Got some html with javascript in, the javascript creates an MSXml2 object and loads some XML from a file, and populates a span. However the HTML that's within the XML is being stripped. Is there a way to stop it from doing this?

(pseudocode)
I've tried various combinations of mySpan = blah.GetNode("mynode").text , .value, .innerxml etc. but nothing is working yet.

Comment: Can you modify the XML file that's being loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, as soon as I post it on here my 2 hours of googling pays off, and I discover its simply (psudocode) getNode("mynode").xml !